# How to make an efficient UNION in Oracle?

Tags: performance, oracle, union

I'm using Oracle 11g.

I have 2 related tables: stored values (A) and new values to insert (B). Both are related between them with an id of 3 columns (client, group and personcode). Each table has about 20 other columns (let's call them attributes).

I have to match them so I can know which values are new (id in B and not in A) so I insert them in A, which are equals (id in B and in A with the same attributes) and which are not in the new values (id in A but not in B anymore), so I delete them from the stored values (A).

For instance:

```
A:

client  | group | personcode    | name | surname
_________________________________________________
1       | 1     | 1             | joe   | doe
1       | 1     | 2             | carl  | john
1       | 1     | 3             | john  | john
```

B:

```
client  | group | personcode    | name | surname
_________________________________________________
1       | 1     | 1             | joe   | doe
1       | 1     | 3             | john  | john
1       | 1     | 4             | mary  | con
```

In this example, person 4 is new, person 2 should be deleted and 1 and 3 remains the same.

So, I need a query which returns the following results:

```
client  | group | personcode    | action
_________________________________________
1       | 1     | 1             | equal
1       | 1     | 2             | remove
1       | 1     | 3             | equal
1       | 1     | 4             | new
```

What I've made is the following query:

```
   WITH 
   A AS (
    -- select from A table
   ), 
   B AS
   (
       -- select from B table
   ),     
   delete AS 
   (
    -- select from A WHERE NOT EXISTS (B.id = A.ID)
   ),       
   news AS 
   (
    -- select from B WHERE NOT EXISTS (A.id = B.ID)
   ),
   eq AS 
   (
    -- select A.* from A, B WHERE A.id = B.id AND A.attributes = B.attributes
   ) 
   select action.client, action.group, action.personcode, 'remove' from delete action
   UNION ALL
   select action.client, action.group, action.personcode, 'new' from news action
   UNION ALL
   select action.client, action.group, action.personcode, 'equal' from eq action
   ;
```

The problem is that, although each of those 3 lasts selects runs in less than 10 seconds, when I merge them using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, the complete query lasts about 90 seconds, even if delete or new or equal are empty. It could be more than 3000 rows in A or in B.

Is there any way to get this results in a better, faster way?

Comment: Another clue to find the guilty... In the inner queries at delete, news and eq, I was filtering for client= ? and group = ?, so I get just the persons of this group of this client. When I remove this filter, this queries don't run in 10 seconds as before. Delete one takes 50 secs, news takes less than 1 sec and eq takes 6 secs.

Comment: OK, another clue: if I insert this id filter in A and B queries, then the complete query takes just 12 seconds, because it's just considering the rows for this id. The problem is that this is the query used by a view, so I can't take this ids by paramter, can I?

Comment: For an efficient union, don't use an oracle. Use an efficient clergyman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks all for your reply. 
I've finally made a view to which I pass some parameters to filter the first two queries, using the strategy described in [this blog](http://halimdba.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/how-to-pass-parameter-to-oracle-view-1.html)
The complete process lasts 30 secs now, and 0 if there are no rows at A or B (before, it lasts 90 secs always).
This is the solution which less affects my current procedures.

Answer (score 4):

You could outer join the tables to produce a log of the differences between them.

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id) id,
       case when a.id is null
              then 'new'
            when b.id is null
              then 'remove'
            when a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 ...
              then 'same'
            else 'different'
        end
from    a full outer join b on (a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: If col1 is NULLABLE, use WHEN (a.col1=b.col1) OR (a.col1 IS NULL AND b.col1 IS NULL)...

Answer (score 2):

If the table B has the data that you want, why do you not use that table instead of that in table A? Create a synonym that points to the one with the correct data in it and reference that.

Comment: table B and A have different values. At first, A is empty. After some processes, some rows are inserted in B. These are new rows which should be stored in A. After some processes are run again, then A and B should be merged (new rows in B should be inserted in A and rows that are in A and not in B, should be deleted)

Comment: I undertsand that. But what you seem to be doing with this process is making the data in table A the same as the data in table B, by inserting, updating, and deleting. So if the data in table A is to match the data in table B at the end of this process, you could just trunctate A and reload from B, or perform a partition exchange to swap the data, or just repoint the queries that need the data to table B via a synonym.

Comment: Yes, my explanation is not quite exact. You're right that, if this is what I want to do, truncating B to A should be a solution. However, what I have to do when deleting/inserting a row is notify another application that this person should be deleted/inserted, and generate an XML with the changes, not only the delete/insert itself.

Comment: You can detect those situations with an outer join between the tables.